# How to Search & Copy All Pictures on the PC into a single folder while preserving Directory Structure?

Tags: backup, search, file-transfer

I want to **transfer all the pictures on the PC** which are scattered into so many locations and drives to a **single location** to any one of the hard drives. Let's call the new location **"folder9".** In folder9 I have to copy the pictures in such a way that they are put into sub-folders that have the same name as that folders/subfolders the pics are put in now.

I am not much familiar with programming, languages and scripts etc. but I need a solution desperately so I am willing to use scripts/commands etc. It would be of great help if you people explain the answers step by step.

**System Specs:**
OS:        WINDOWS 8.1
RAM:       4 GB
PROCESSOR: INTEL i3

**What I tried till now:**
I tried using everything search and searched all the pictures on the pc (about 50,980) and then produced a .txt list and .csv list of the pictures calong with complete info like path, name etc.

I'd like to be able to use this list if possible, with some command or third party software

Comment: Have a look at Robocopy.

Comment: How to use Robocopy? Plz some step-by-step process?

Comment: Magsi, read this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851678.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

`robocopy C:\ "<path_to_folder9>" *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif /e`

You can use that command for any of your drives, but it will keep only the newest file if you have a file in the same path with the same name on more that one drives. Alternatively, you can do it with a destination per drive like this:

`robocopy C:\ "<path_to_folder9>\C" *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif /e`

It doesn't use the lists you created, but everything I can think of that does is a lot more work.

Comment: I am having problem and this error is being returned to me ERROR 123 <0x0000007B> ACCESSING DESTINATION DIRECTORY C:\users\dell\<ndir>\. the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. NOTE: I renamed "folder9" to "ndir"

Comment: Remove < and >.

Answer (score 0):

These two worked like a charm:

robocopy C:\ D:\destinationFolder *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif /MIR

robocopy C:\ D:\destinationFolder *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif /s *.jpeg *.jpg *.png *.gif /a-:rsh /r:0 /w:0

/a-:rsh //this removes the read-only, System and Hidden attributes on the coped files
/s copies subfolders, except empty ones

..the first one seems impeccable though